# How to warp image using opencv in ios?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I need to detect facial features in the image provided by the user and then apply different effects to the facial features.

Answer (score 0):

All of this can be found in the documentation. Information about warping can be found on the page about [geometric transformations](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html). Information how to detect facial features can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html).